# LWC constructor and wire adapter

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom, constructor

Already wire adapter was there in LWC i.e. @wire annotation to display  the records,so can we do the same thing (display the records) through LWC constructor also?
If yes, then why @wire feature  was introduced in LWC??

Comment: I'm not at all clear on what you are asking. What does it mean to "display records through LWC constructor"? Please [edit] your post to provide clarity and concrete examples.

Comment: Yeah.. Did that

Comment: Your edit did not add any more information on what you are trying to do or ask. Please review [ask] and [help/on-topic], take a step back, and try again to explain the technical problem or question you are struggling with.

Comment: I think I got the answer through sfdcfox... No more edits required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call out to the server in the `constructor()` or `connectedCallback()` synchronously. They will be delayed, as asynchronous calls, until at least the first `renderedCallback()` cycle. As such, `@wire` methods provide the same results with less code (potentially just one line of code).

Comment: Thnx again for your awesome help.. @sfdcfox... Much appreciated as this question was asked in interview